# For loop not running in python and pygame

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a bingo programs that takes the user input for their numbers and number of boards. Then whenever the number gets called, they type it in and it displays on screen. So it is like a tracker program. Anyways, I am trying to get this for loop running so the program knows what numbers are being called. The problem is that it is not even running. It does not ask me for a call number. I am sure it is something simple I am missing. Here is that portion of the code. This is in a function by the way.

```
global previous_numbers_called
previous_numbers_called=[]
for i in range(75):
    called=int(input("Enter number called:"))
    previous_numbers_called.append(called)
```

Here is my entire code just in case you need it.

```
import pygame
import math
import color
import sys
import os
import random
import cx_Freeze
import time
import glob
pygame.init()
white=color.white
black=color.black
blue=color.blue
screen_width=800
screen_height=600
gamedisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Bingo Tracker')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
FPS=60
the_x=pygame.image.load('mark.png')
instructions=pygame.image.load('bingotrackerinstructions.png')
bingocard=pygame.image.load('bingocard.png')
arrow=pygame.image.load('arrow.png')
super_smallfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(screen_width/80))
smallfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(screen_width/32))
mediumfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(screen_width/16))
largefont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(screen_width/10))
def intro_screen():
    start_message = mediumfont.render(str("Welcome to Bingo Tracker!!!"), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(start_message,(screen_width/5.614035088,screen_height/40))
    gamedisplay.blit(instructions,(0,-20))
    gamedisplay.blit(bingocard,(300,375))
    gamedisplay.blit(arrow,(300,250))
    pygame.display.update()
def board_1():         #left to right       13 is freespace
    square_1=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((0,0),(50,50)),2)
    square_2=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((50,0),(50,50)),2)
    square_3=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((100,0),(50,50)),2)
    square_4=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((150,0),(50,50)),2)
    square_5=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((200,0),(50,50)),2)
    square_6=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((0,50),(50,50)),2)
    square_7=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((50,50),(50,50)),2)
    square_8=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((100,50),(50,50)),2)
    square_9=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((150,50),(50,50)),2)
    square_10=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((200,50),(50,50)),2)
    square_11=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((0,100),(50,50)),2)
    square_12=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((50,100),(50,50)),2)
    square_13=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((100,100),(50,50)),2)
    square_14=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((150,100),(50,50)),2)
    square_15=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((200,100),(50,50)),2)
    square_16=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((0,150),(50,50)),2)
    square_17=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((50,150),(50,50)),2)
    square_18=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((100,150),(50,50)),2)
    square_19=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((150,150),(50,50)),2)
    square_20=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((200,150),(50,50)),2)
    square_21=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((0,200),(50,50)),2)
    square_22=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((50,200),(50,50)),2)
    square_23=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((100,200),(50,50)),2)
    square_24=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((150,200),(50,50)),2)
    square_25=pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, black,((200,200),(50,50)),2)
    freespace_1 = smallfont.render(str("Free"), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(freespace_1,(105,110))
    gamedisplay.blit(the_x,(100,100))
    number_of_x_board_1=1
    board_1_first_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_second_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_third_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_forth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_fifth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_sixth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_seventh_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_eighth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_ninth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_tenth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_eleventh_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_twelvth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_thirdteenth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_forthteenth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_fifthteenth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_sixthteenth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_seventeenth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_eighthteenth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_ninthteenth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_twentyth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_twentyfirst_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_twentysecond_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_twentythird_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    board_1_twentyforth_number=int(input("Enter your numbers for board number 1:"))
    text_board1_1=smallfont.render(str(board_1_first_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_1,(13,9))    #x+13,y+9
    text_board1_2=smallfont.render(str(board_1_second_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_2,(63,9))
    text_board1_3=smallfont.render(str(board_1_third_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_3,(113,9))
    text_board1_4=smallfont.render(str(board_1_forth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_4,(163,9))
    text_board1_5=smallfont.render(str(board_1_fifth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_5,(213,9))
    text_board1_6=smallfont.render(str(board_1_sixth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_6,(13,59))
    text_board1_7=smallfont.render(str(board_1_seventh_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_7,(63,59))
    text_board1_8=smallfont.render(str(board_1_eighth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_8,(113,59))
    text_board1_9=smallfont.render(str(board_1_ninth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_9,(163,59))
    text_board1_10=smallfont.render(str(board_1_tenth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_10,(213,59))
    text_board1_11=smallfont.render(str(board_1_eleventh_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_11,(13,109))
    text_board1_12=smallfont.render(str(board_1_twelvth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_12,(63,109))
    text_board1_13=smallfont.render(str(board_1_thirdteenth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_13,(163,109))
    text_board1_14=smallfont.render(str(board_1_forthteenth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_14,(213,109))
    text_board1_15=smallfont.render(str(board_1_fifthteenth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_15,(13,159))
    text_board1_16=smallfont.render(str(board_1_sixthteenth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_16,(63,159))
    text_board1_17=smallfont.render(str(board_1_seventeenth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_17,(113,159))
    text_board1_18=smallfont.render(str(board_1_eighthteenth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_18,(163,159))
    text_board1_19=smallfont.render(str(board_1_ninthteenth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_19,(213,159))
    text_board1_20=smallfont.render(str(board_1_twentyth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_20,(13,209))
    text_board1_21=smallfont.render(str(board_1_twentyfirst_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_21,(63,209))
    text_board1_22=smallfont.render(str(board_1_twentysecond_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_22,(113,209))
    text_board1_23=smallfont.render(str(board_1_twentythird_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_23,(163,209))
    text_board1_24=smallfont.render(str(board_1_twentyforth_number), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(text_board1_24,(213,209))

    #the input numbers go here,
    #then you can get text right in here also.
    #then you can just make more of the boards and based on what number of
    #boards, then it will run the required number of board functions.
    #Use 2 loops to take care of memory retain information
def gameloop():
    gamedisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        try:
            number_of_boards=int(input("How many boards do you have?:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid board number.")
            number_of_boards=int(input("How many boards do you have?:"))
        if number_of_boards<1:
            print("Sorry, you must enter a number of 1 or greater.")
            number_of_boards=int(input("How many boards do you have?:"))
        else:
            break
    if number_of_boards==1:
        board_1()
    pygame.display.update()
    stop=True
    while stop==True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    stop=False
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    quit()
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    global previous_numbers_called
    previous_numbers_called=[]
    for i in range(75):
        called=int(input("Enter number called:"))
        previous_numbers_called.append(called)
    pygame.display.update()       
gamedisplay.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()
intro_screen()
are_you_done_reading=input("Enter y once you're done reading:").lower()
while not are_you_done_reading=='y':
    pass
gameloop()
```

Comment: You're code is very redundant and quite unreadable. Try splitting tasks into many functions so you can organize it

Comment: You're defining `i` as the loop incrementor and then you're overriding it in the body of the for-loop...

Comment: I am still confused. If I am overriding it, then why can't I create a variable inside the for loop that is not the loop letter than then append that variable? Code still doesn't run when I do that. Can you show me? As to Andrew L's comment, I don't know where I would create another function as they all seem to fit. Like the board function has everything it needs. The game loop has the task of calling the other functions. How could I make it less "redundant?" Looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Ok, how about an example like this. Why won't this work?                                                                list_1=[]                                                                                                            for x in range(75):                                                                                                   ask=int(input("Enter numbers"))     #This would be indented                                list_1.append(ask)                #This would be indented

Comment: Ok, I changed it so that I am not using the i letter. Why won't this work either?